# How to show first preserve_default_filters! and after custom filter

Tags: activeadmin

I have this in my code:

```
  preserve_default_filters!
  filter :oculto,
    as: :check_boxes,
    collection: [['Oculto', true], ['visible', false]],
    label: 'Mostrar'
```

I want to show default filters first and show after my custom filter, but I don't know how.

*I attached a sample of my index page, how it shows it and how I want it*[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box but reading through the code I found https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/1290efa1fc7984badebe774f108d886a1e82624c/lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb#L93..L97 which led me to replace `preserve_default_filters!` above with:

```
config.send(:default_filters).each { |f| filter f }
filter :oculto ...
```

This takes the default filters and inserts them before yours. It might be interesting to submit a pull request adding this to `lib/activeadmin/filters/dsl.rb`:

```
def default_filters
  config.send(:default_filters).each { |f| filter f }
end
```

Then you would be able to register the resource with:

```
default_filters
filter :oculto ...
```